# Element UI Datetime Picker disable hour and minute before current time

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using element-ui 2.15.7. How can i disable hour and minute before current time. For example, current time is 27/11/2023 1:41 pm, so i want the date picker to disable 0 -> 12 in hour (only show 13 hour -> 23) when i click on day 27, and 41 -> 59 in minute (because the current minute is 41). Current the library **disabledDate** prop only allows disable whole date, not allows partial disable

Comment: You can replace `DateTimePicker` with separate `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`. Then you will be able to use the `minTime` and `maxTime` settings or `selectableRange` to limit the hours.

Comment: Actually, i only want limit the time when user selects date equal current date. For example, today is 24/11 so when user clicks day 24 on calendar the hour and minute will be limited, but if user clicks 25/11, they can choose any hour and minute they want

Comment: Currently, you can not achieve your goal by using `DateTimePicker` component. Instead, use `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` in your own component.